# MySQL 5.6 - Creating an event inside a stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-5.6, mysql-event

I am trying to create a procedure which create an event in MySQL.

For example, something similar to this:

```
delimiter //
CREATE PROCEDURE schedule_my_db_job() 
  BEGIN

    CREATE EVENT MY_DB_JOB 
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MINUTE DO 
    BEGIN 
        SELECT * FROM information_schema.events; -- for example
    END;      

  END//
delimiter ;
```

But it gives me following error when I try to create this procedure.

```
ERROR 1576 (HY000): Recursion of EVENT DDL statements is forbidden when body is present
```

As I understand MySQL allow stored procedures to have CREATE EVENT sql statement inside. (Quotation from https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-event.html  "You can create an event as part of a stored routine, but an event cannot be created by another event")

Could you please let me know what is the error here?

Thanks.

Comment: Try without the Begin and End for your select inside the event:    CREATE EVENT e_hourly
    ON SCHEDULE
      EVERY 1 HOUR
    COMMENT 'Clears out sessions table each hour.'
    DO
      DELETE FROM site_activity.sessions;

Comment: Thanks, but this also gives me the same error. It seems MySQL doesn't allow event creation inside a stored procedure. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/stored-program-restrictions.html#stored-routines-event-restrictions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is a conflict in MySQL documentation.
I think [CREATE EVENT Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-event.html) section in MySQL documentation is not correctly updated in later versions. Although "CREATE EVENT Syntax" sections says

> You can create an event as part of a stored routine, but an event
>   cannot be created by another event.

In [Event Scheduler Restrictions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/stored-program-restrictions.html#stored-routines-event-restrictions) section in mysql documentation, 
It says

> An **event may not be created**, altered, or dropped **by a stored routine**,
>   trigger, or another event. An event also may not create, alter, or
>   drop stored routines or triggers. (Bug #16409, Bug #18896)

Comment: Has this been rectified in 5.6.23?